# What are the pros and cons of how you place your Xbox 360?

Tags: xbox-360

I have recently gotten an Xbox 360 Elite and I wish to make it last as long as possible.

My question would is it better to set it on its side with the disc tray horizontal? Or, should it be standing on its end with the disc tray vertical? Is one orientation more likely to scratch disks or cause overheating?

Comment: I never heard that there was special orientation that prolonged life.  Just treat it like a PC when it comes to air flow and spacing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

General consensus is that it's better for the XBOX if it's laid on its side with the disc tray horizontal as there's no risk of knocking it over and rendering discs unplayable (which I've done twice).

The only pros I've heard of for standing it upright is that it "looks cooler," takes up less space if space is limited, and also ventilation is *allegedly* better, which I don't really buy since all sides of the console have ventilation holes of some kind (I've had mine horizontal for four years and have yet to encounter any sort over overheating or discs getting scratched).